# Angular - auto updating a web app version on the client

Tags: javascript, angular, continuous-integration

I have seen many techniques on the web, the most common one is a pop up toast message that says there is a new version and you are asked to reload the page (in google's Inbox for example)
As far as I understand, the only thing that is not cached is index.html, where are the references to the .js bundles with unique version hashing.

My question is - is this the best technique out there? Is it recommended to use a Service Worker for push messages on new version, or to have a request every few seconds to the server asking if there is new version? What is the full architecture?

Couldn't find any elegant solution for a good CI/CD technique for web apps (mostly Angular), that will mimc web app version updates (like in the app/play store)

Any thoughts?